# too many levels of recursion when trying to plot recursive function

Tags: math, plot, maple

I'm trying to plot the graph of a recursive function in Maple 17 but I keep getting the error **Error, (in f) too many levels of recursion**.

I need to plot a logarithmic graph in the range of x=1,...40.
Here is the code:

```
with(plots); 
f:=x->(2.25*f(x-1)-0.5*f(x-2));
f(1):=1/3;
f(2):=1/12;
logplot(f(x),1..40);
```

How can I fix this problem? Maybe I need to write it in an iterative form, but I don't know how.
Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comment, if you do the following, then you will get a graph very close to the one you got in Matlab.

```
Digits:= 15:

f:= proc(n)
option remember;
     if not n::posint then 'procname'(args)
     else 2.25*thisproc(n-1) - 0.5*thisproc(n-2)
     end if
end proc:
f(1):= 1/3:  f(2):= 1/12:

f_exact:= proc(n)
option remember;
     if not n::posint then 'procname'(args)
     else 9/4*thisproc(n-1) - 1/2*thisproc(n-2)
     end if
end proc:
f_exact(1):= 1/3:  f_exact(2):= 1/12:

plots:-logplot([
      [seq([x, abs(f(x))], x= 1..40)], 
      [seq([x,f_exact(x)], x= 1..40)]
]);
```

[image: The plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your function is extremely sensitive to floating-point errors. You must use exact arithmetic in computing the values of f. If you don't, then you'll get negative function values, and then using logarithms won't make sense.

Also, your function is only defined for integer values of n. You have to somehow inform the plot command of that.

```
f:= proc(n)
option remember;
     if not n::posint then 'procname'(args)
     else 9/4*thisproc(n-1) - 1/2*thisproc(n-2)
     end if
end proc:
f(1):= 1/3:  f(2):= 1/12:
plot([seq([x,log10(f(x))], x= 1..40)]);
```

[image]

Comment: I Think I need to explain myself better: My homework is to plot the graph of f in it's recursive form and then compare between it and the graph of f in it's direct form (this is the plot that you gave). My goal is to get something like that:
![IMG]http://i.imgur.com/uzfGsYh.png[/IMG]
Thanks for your help!

Comment: My f *is* in the recursive form. The direct form is what you get with **rsolve**, as you were shown when you asked this same question on MaplePrimes. I think the goal of your exercise is to plot the floating-point form to show the errors. But we can't use logarithms for that because the function goes negative. We could use the logarithm of the absolute value.

Comment: You are right, I understood. If so, my question is how can I in Maple plot the graphs like in the image I gave (the image is from Matlab)? Sorry for so many questions, I'm new in Maple.
Thanks a lot!